# Update table in Sql

Tags: sql

Table `tblProductStock`:

```
ID    Name    Qyt
1      X       50
2      Y       40
3      Z       30
```

Table `tblStockMinus`:

```
Id   Name  Qty
1     X    10
1     X    20
2     Y    30 
3     Z    20
```

I want to update `tblProductStock` so that it will have:

```
ID    Name    Qyt
1      X       20
2      Y       10
3      Z       10
```

I have tried to use the following SQL request, but it didn't work correctly:

```
UPDATE ProductStock_Show
SET Quantity = ProductStock_Show.Quantity - ProductStock_Show_Minus.Quantity
FROM ProductStock_Show JOIN ProductStock_Show_Minus
ON ProductStock_Show_Minus.ProductId=ProductStock_Show.ProductId
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? Have a go yourself first, then when you have issues, post your attempted code and we can help

Comment: how did you decide that the `tblProductStock` with the `Name` `X` did get the value `20` and not `10`?

Comment: Describe what you are trying to do. Why this result

Comment: UPDATE ProductStock_Show
SET Quantity = ProductStock_Show.Quantity - ProductStock_Show_Minus.Quantity
FROM ProductStock_Show
 JOIN ProductStock_Show_Minus ON  ProductStock_Show_Minus.ProductId=ProductStock_Show.ProductId 


but not correct.

Comment: It's a easy query. Try again using `sum` function.

Comment: can you send me quary.plzzz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you required result.

```
select t1.id, t1.qty-t2.qty as qty from tblProductStock as t1 inner join
(
select id, sum(qty) as qty from tblStockMinus group by id
) as t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

You need to update this (but it depends in the RDBMS. This is for MS SQL Server)

```
Update t
set
t.qty=t3.qty from tblProductStock as t inner join
(
    select t1.id, t1.qty-t2.qty as qty from tblProductStock as t1 inner join
    (
    select id, sum(qty) as qty from tblStockMinus group by id
    ) as t2 on t1.id=t2.id
) as t3 on t.id=t3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE  @Table1 TABLE 
    ( ID  int,  Name  varchar(1),  Qyt  int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ( ID ,  Name ,  Qyt )
VALUES
    (1, 'X', 50),
    (2, 'Y', 40),
    (3, 'Z', 30)
;


DECLARE @Table2 TABLE 
    ( Id  int,  Name  varchar(1),  Qty  int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table2
    ( Id ,  Name ,  Qty )
VALUES
    (1, 'X', 10),
    (1, 'X', 20),
    (2, 'Y', 30),
    (3, 'Z', 20)
;
UPDATE @Table1 SET QYT = 
   t.Qyt - s from (
select 
t.id,
t.Name,
t.Qyt , 
SUM(tt.Qty)S 
    FROM @Table1 t 
INNER JOIN @Table2 tt
ON t.Name = tt.Name
GROUP BY t.id,t.Name,t.Qyt)T

SELECT * from @Table1
```